# Как устранить ошибку? "map" object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.7

Пользователь вводит последовательность из чисел, нужно определить, является последовательность монотонно возрастающей или убывающей(в т.ч. и нестрого) и вывести "Да" или "Нет".
При запуске программы выдает

> 'map' object is not subscriptable.

Что нужно исправить, чтобы заработало?

```py
a = map(int, input().split(" "))
prev = a[0]
flag = True 
for i in a[1:]:
    if prev <= i:
        prev = i
    else:
        flag = False
        break
if flag: print("Yes")
else: print("No")
```

Comment: `prev = next(a)`, `for i in a:`

Comment: `a = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Что такое `map`?

Это функция, которая применит первый аргумент (функцию) к каждому элементу второго аргумента (коллекции), но в python3 это не происходит сразу, как в python2, где `map` возвращает список:

```py
>>> map(int, "12345")
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

А постепенно, т.к. `map` возвращает итератор "map object":

```py
>>> map(int, "12345")
<map object at 0x000001D51030BB50>
```

И как все итераторы, мы можем итерировать по `map` с помощью `next`:

```py
>>> m = map(int, "12345")
>>> next(m)
1
>>> next(m)
2
>>> next(m)
3
>>> next(m)
4
>>> next(m)
5
>>> next(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Или же с помощь. `for` цикла:

```py
>>> for i in map(int, "12345"):
...     print(i)
...
1
2
3
4
5
```

## В чём проблема?

Вы пытаетесь получить первый элемент итератора, но т.к. у итератор нет элементов, он создаёт их "на лету", то и питон на это жалуется:

```py
>>> map(int, "12345")[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable
```

Что же вы хотите сделать - превратить `map` в коллекцию, например `list`, тогда и по индексу можно будет обращаться:

```py
>>> result = list(map(int, "12345"))
>>> result[0]
1
>>> for i in result[1:]:
...     print(i)
...
2
3
4
5
```

## Альтернатива

В питоне также есть `comprehension`s - это способ инициализировать что-то, в нашем случае список:

```py
>>> [int(i) for i in "12345"]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Здесь используется `for` цикл, чтобы создавать значения, а значение `int(i)` уже записывается в конечный список.

## Хитрость

Вы использовали `flag`, чтобы проверить, вышли ли вы из цикла с помощью `break`, но в питоне есть специальный синтаксис для этого - `for .. else ..`:

```py
>>> for i in 1, 2, 3:
...     if i == 2:
...             print("нашёл")
...             break
... else:
...     print("не нашёл")
...
нашёл
```

Если мы выходим из цикла через `break`, то `else` будет проигнорирован

```py
>>> for i in 1, 3:
...     if i == 2:
...             print("нашёл")
...             break
... else:
...     print("не нашёл")
...
не нашёл
```

А если не выйдем, то выполнится.

## Итог

Если мы применим наши новые знания, то получим:

```py
a = [int(i) for i in input().split(" ")]

prev = a[0]

for i in a[1:]:
    if prev <= i:
        prev = i
    else:
        print("No")
        break
else:
    print("Yes")
```

или

```py
a = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))

prev = a[0]

for i in a[1:]:
    if prev <= i:
        prev = i
    else:
        print("No")
        break
else:
    print("Yes")
```

в зависимости от того, что вы предпочитаете, `map` или `comprehension`.
(как по мне, `comprehension`s намного более интуитивные :] )

Comment: @Алексей если вам помог или понравится этот ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте [проголосовать и отметить ответ как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)